# android eclipse error:Error: no resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/red')

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

This is definitely driving me a little crazy because I am literally at tutorial one of learning android and I have already encountered a pair of problems.

First being that when I apply `android:gravity="center"` the text only centers vertically but not horizontally, then to make matters worse if I change the helloworld example textview `android:text="@string/red"` and then go to the **strings.xml** and change the default value to  `<string name="red">redflashlight</string>` the graphical layout shows the text as `@string/red` instead of **"redflashlight"**.

This is concerning because I am literally following a video tutorial and I am doing exactly what the author is doing, I am worried that perhaps its a problem with the sdk or eclipse? perhaps my operating system being vista? I really dont know, any help would b amazing thanks in advance.

here is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
>    
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/red"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="red">redflashlight</string>
<string name="app_name">simple flashlight</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Did you put main.xml in "res/layout" and strings.xml in "res/values" folders?

Comment: yes both are in the correct folders sitting under the res folder, but the problem still persists, with the default hello world example its fine but then doesn't work when I change variable names :/

Comment: I may have figured it out it appears this tutorial is out of date my apologies!

Answer (score 0):

To make the text center in both vertically and horizontally,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
><TextView  
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/red"
/></LinearLayout>
```

I try your code and its working properly. I think your project is not build properly. So, build it:
Project->Build Automatically from the menu bar of eclipse.

Comment: Instead of keying in the xml manually I used the android resources UI instead and it worked, this seems to be the way forward!